# C# Upload file larger as 2mb

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, file-upload

I managed to upload files less than 2mb, but since I also want to upload larger files I had to move away from CSOM.

So I searched the web and found this solution:

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("https://mysharepoint.com/sites/testing/");
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("user@sharepoint.com", passWord);
Folder folder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("test");
string file = String.Concat(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"\a.pdb");

List docLib = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("test");
ctx.Load(docLib);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)))
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, "/test/a.pdb", stream, true);
}
```

but it exits with the message:

> 401 not authorized

Seems to be a known issue in current SharePoint versions, but i also saw on other posts here, that it got fixed a while ago and should work?

Comment: Can you try this 
            Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, "/sites/testing/test/a.pdb", stream, true); let me still you get error

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference.

```
string targetSiteURL = @"https://mysharepoint.com/sites/testing/";

var login = "lz@xxx.onmicrosoft.com";
var password = "password";

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in password)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}

ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(targetSiteURL);
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);

string file = @"c:\temp\a.pdb";

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(file)))
{
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(ctx, "/sites/testing/test/a.pdb", stream, true);
}
```

And check if the login account and password are right.

If you use SharePoint On-premise, we need using the below code to pass Credentials.

```
ctx.Credentials=new NetworkCredential("username", "password","domain");
```